# Copying column from one data frame to another based on matching of combination of two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have got two dataframes (i.e. df1 and df2).

df1 contains date and time columns. Time columns contains 30 minutes interval of time series:

```
df1:
         date      time
0       2015-04-01  00:00:00
1       2015-04-01  00:30:00
2       2015-04-01  01:00:00
3       2015-04-01  01:30:00
4       2015-04-01  02:00:00
```

df2 contains date, start-time, end-time, value:

```
df2
       INCIDENT_DATE INTERRUPTION_TIME RESTORE_TIME  WASTED_MINUTES
0        2015-04-01             00:32        01:15          1056.0
1        2015-04-01             01:20        02:30          3234.0
2        2015-04-01             01:22        03:30          3712.0
3        2015-04-01             01:30        03:15          3045.0
```

Now I want to copy the wasted_minutes column from df2 to df1 when date columns of both data frames are the same and Interruption_time of the column of df2 lies in the time column of df1. So the output should look like:

```
df1:
                date      time      Wasted_columns
    0       2015-04-01  00:00:00       NaN
    1       2015-04-01  00:30:00       1056.0
    2       2015-04-01  01:00:00       6946.0
    3       2015-04-01  01:30:00       3045.0
    4       2015-04-01  02:00:00       NaN
```

I tried merge command (on the basis of date column), but didn't produce the desired result, because I am not sure how to check whether time falls in 30 minutes intervals or not? Could anyone guide how to fix the issue?

Comment: Hi, what if interruption time and restore_time just cover 2 date time

Comment: always go with interruption time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `time` to timedelta and assign back to `df1`. Convert `INTERRUPTION_TIME` to timedelta and `floor` it to 30-minute interval and assign to `s`. Groupby `df2` by `INCIDENT_DATE`, `s` and call `sum` of `WASTED_MINUTES`. Finally, `join` the result of `groupby` back to `df1`

```
df1['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['time'].astype(str)) #cast to str before calling `to_timedelta`
s = pd.to_timedelta(df2.INTERRUPTION_TIME+':00').dt.floor('30Min')
df_final = df1.join(df2.groupby(['INCIDENT_DATE', s]).WASTED_MINUTES.sum(), 
                    on=['date', 'time'])

Out[631]:
         date     time  WASTED_MINUTES
0  2015-04-01 00:00:00             NaN
1  2015-04-01 00:30:00          1056.0
2  2015-04-01 01:00:00          6946.0
3  2015-04-01 01:30:00          3045.0
4  2015-04-01 02:00:00             NaN
```

Comment: Here is the error: You are trying to merge on object and timedelta64[ns] columns.

Comment: @user2293224: could you check `df1['time']` is in timedelta dtype?

Comment: df1['time'] is object. I modified the code : Modification was I used .astype(str) while converting time in your code. It executed. However, it  WASTED_MINUTES column had NaN values. Any suggestion?

Comment: in my code `s` is timedelta, so you need to keep `df1['time']` in timedelta dtype to make `join` work. Otherwise, if you want to convert `df1['time']` to object, you also need to convert `s` to object before calling the `groupby` inside of `join`

Comment: When I converted s into .astype(str), the error was ValueError: You are trying to merge on timedelta64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: what are values of `s` and `df1['time']` after `.astype(str)` and before calling `join`? Could you add them in the question because comment section is not enough space?

Comment: you need to keep both `s` and `df['time']` either in dtype object or timedelta. the last error indicates one of them are not in timedelta dtype

Comment: You are right. Value of S changes when I convert into str. When I tried to convert df1['time'] into timedelta. It throws an error ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>

Comment: 0 days added as prefix the value of s and .000000000 added as suffix when I convert s into str

Comment: yes, It is the reason I want to keep both of them in timedelta instead of object. You `df1['time']` is python datetime.time, not string as I expect. You need cast it to `str` before call `to_timedelta`. I edited the answer to add it. Check the updated

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
df1['time']=pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])
df1['Wasted_columns']=df1.apply(lambda x: df2.loc[(pd.to_datetime(df2['INTERRUPTION_TIME'])>= x['time']) & (pd.to_datetime(df2['INTERRUPTION_TIME'])< x['time']+pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)),'WASTED_MINUTES'].sum(), axis=1)
df1['time']=df1['time'].dt.time
```

If you convert the 'time' column in the lambda function itself, then it is just one line of code as below

```
df1['Wasted_columns']=df1.apply(lambda x: df2.loc[(pd.to_datetime(df2['INTERRUPTION_TIME'])>= pd.to_datetime(x['time'])) & (pd.to_datetime(df2['INTERRUPTION_TIME'])< pd.to_datetime(x['time'])+pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)),'WASTED_MINUTES'].sum(), axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
          date     time     Wasted_columns
0   2015-04-01  00:00:00    0.0
1   2015-04-01  00:30:00    1056.0
2   2015-04-01  01:00:00    6946.0
3   2015-04-01  01:30:00    3045.0
4   2015-04-01  02:00:00    0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea:
 + Convert to datetime
 + Round to nearest 30 mins
 + Merge

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def ceil_dt(dt, delta):
    return dt + (datetime.min - dt) % delta

# Convert
df1['dt'] = (df1['date'] + ' ' + df1['time']).apply(datetime.strptime, args=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'])
df2['dt'] = (df2['INCIDENT_DATE '] + ' ' + df2['INTERRUPTION_TIME']).apply(datetime.strptime, args=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'])

# Round
def ceil_dt(dt, delta):
    return dt + (datetime.min - dt) % delta

df2['dt'] = df2['dt'].apply(ceil_dt, args=[timedelta(minutes=30)])

# Merge
final = df1.merge(df2.loc[:, ['dt', 'wasted_column'], on='dt', how='left'])
```

Also if multiple incidents happens in 30 mins timeframe, you would want to group by on df2 with rounded dt col first to sum up wasted then merge